# Is there a way to get a Kindle Fire to work with 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, kindle

My mom is getting a Kindle Fire, and she uses Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit. 
I need to find a program to have her Kindle working with her Ubuntu machine. 
I would really hate it if we couldn't find an app for it.

thanks for any help!!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/203618/46709

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very handsome utility out into world which helps you to manage your Kindle ebooks and which is also an excellent viewer for it. The application is called "Calibre". There are thousands of websites which link to Calibre but you can see its installation instruction here:
http://blog.sudobits.com/2010/09/05/how-to-install-calibre-on-ubuntu/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. with try it out tonight. ill give check mark if its good!

Answer (score 0):

Calibre is the software you want to use.

As for getting ubuntu to recognize the Kindle, try reading the following thread.  Essentially, the newer Kindles use MTP instead of the usual storage device protocol, which is not installed by default in Ubunutu.
[Managing Kindle Fire with on 12.04 via Micro-USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177555/managing-kindle-fire-with-on-12-04-via-micro-usb)